# Altium PCB Parameter Live Updating Issue

Tags: pcb, altium

I have two PCBs open at the same time... one of them live updates parameter strings (i.e. '.Print Date') as soon as I place them, the other just shows the meta text. However the 'broken' one still outputs to PDFs/Gerbers correctly. I've hunted furiously for a solution but Google has failed me this time. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Looks like you need to enable Special Strings for one of the PCBs. What version of Altium ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Altium 17, in your PCB, when you up the View Configurations and select View Options, you'll see an option that says Convert Special Strings.

See: [Documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/17.1/display/ADES/PCB_Dlg-LayerConfigurationForm_pnlHolder_Panel_Right_pnl2DSimpleConfigHolder_pgcSimple2DConfiguration_sheetBoardLayersAndColors((View%20Configurations%20-%20Board%20Layers%20and%20Colors%20tab))_AD/?help-data=PCB.Dlg.LayerConfigurationForm.pnlHolder.Panel_Right.pnl2DSimpleConfigHolder.pgcSimple2DConfiguration.sheetBoardLayersAndColors.pnl2DSimpleBoardColors.Panel_Main.pnl_LCSignalMaskSilk.XPExtPanel.Grid_SignalLayers) for more information.

I cannot seem to find it Altium 18, so I think it might always be enabled.

According to the their documentation, it is always enabled.

> The Convert Special Strings option has been removed since the string
>   is always displayed; if null, then the parameter name is displayed.

Source: [Link](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/NFS_18_0((A+Fresh+User+Interface))_AD)

[image]